# L'« impression d'artiste » pour l'« illustration accompagnant un thème spéculatif, généralement technique ou scientifique » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, terminologie, anglicismes, faux-amis

J'ai vu quelques articles sur l'espace où l'on a des images qui ont comme légende « impression d'artiste du/de la... » (ex. ...[*de la station Gateway*](https://www.lapresse.ca/actualites/sciences/2022-08-28/programme-artemis/les-humains-de-nouveau-en-route-vers-la-lune.php)) plutôt que « [vue/représentation d'artiste](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/artiste/5584/locution?q=vue%20d%20artiste#752405) », possiblement un calque de l'anglais [*artist's impression*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vue_d%27artiste#French) ; j'ai par ailleurs trouvé « [vue conceptuelle](https://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=18984709) ».

- Le terme « impression d'artiste » pour désigner le *artist's
  impression* est-il un calque, une extension de sens abusive du mot
  *impression* ou est-il en usage, valable ?
- Entre la *vue*, la *représentation d'artiste* et la *vue
  conceptuelle*, laquelle est le plus fréquente ou convient le mieux pour
  désigner une station spatiale ou un corps céleste pour lequel on n'a
  pas d'image ?
- Peut-on ou non remplacer *d'artiste* par l'adjectif [*artistique*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/artistique) et
  pourquoi ?

Comment: En préalable, il me semble qu'il faudrait savoir quel est le sens du mot *impression* dans l'expression *artist's impression*.

Comment: *une station spatiale ou un corps céleste pour lequel on n'a pas d'image* on peut ajouter que les images de nanostructures, virus ou des processus dans les cellules sont aussi souvent ne que des impressions d'artiste.

Comment: @jlliagre [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artist%27s_impression) parle d'une _representation_, c'est possiblement dans la même catégorie de [sens](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/impression) que l'imitation ou reproduction des éléments remarquables ou traits essentiels. Mais sans en être certain, on peut voir si l'impression peut avoir le sens de représentation. On peut probablement être certain que l'_artist's impression_ n'a rien à voir avec un artiste qui donne ses impressions au figuré par le truchement d'une image qu'il élabore...

Comment: @jlliagre … *Représentation d'artiste* est l'expression la plus souvent (voire la seule dans certains contextes) rencontrées dans les textes d'information tout public, et correspond à l'intuition : « l'artiste imagine (en connaissant le contexte) un objet “connu” (ou dont on a des traces), tel qu'il est suggéré, et jamais photographié, ou pour rendre la photo plus lisible ». *Impression d'artiste* renvoie au ressenti émotionnel de l'artiste, la source n'est pas un objet, mais sa sensibilité.

Comment: @Personne Oui, c'est mon impression aussi ;-) en ce qui concerne le français mais en anglais et dans cette expression, *impression* a semble-t-il un sens inconnu en français (représentation/reproduction/imitation) sauf si on se réfère à une imprimante, ce qui n'est manifestement pas le sujet.

Answer (score 2):

Les termes couramment employés sont *vue d'artiste* et *illustration d'artiste*, simples traductions de l'anglais. Le mot-clé est *artiste*, on peut l'associer aussi à d'autres noms: Dessin, représentation, rendu, etc.

Par *artiste*, on sous-entend que la fidélité n'est pas garantie car ce n'est pas un travail issu d'un bureau d'études.

Parfois on rencontre *vue conceptuelle*, dans le sens anglais de concept (comme dans concept-car), quelque chose qu'il n'est pas abouti, une étape dans la conception du modèle final.

[image]

Source: [Airbus](https://www.airbus.com/sites/g/files/jlcbta136/files/2022-01/FR-Airbus-SpS-Press-Release-Airbus-to-develop-the-Power-Management-and-Distribution-System-for-key-Lunar-Gateway-module.pdf)